# Assistance interpreting MySQL instruction: "To avoid getting this error while trying to drop a foreign key, use the constraint name rather than ..."

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './MyDB/MyTable' to './MyDB/#sql2-e4a-ca3e' (errno: 152)

To avoid getting this error while trying to drop a foreign key, use the **constraint name** rather than the **column name** of the foreign key.

Summary: 

99.999% of the time errors like this have nothing to do with the ability to create a temporary file and much to do with foreign key issues.
```

That's quoted from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html).  I'm unsure what a constraint name is, to be honest.  Could someone produce an example where a constraint is used as opposed to a column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreign key can be specified at a table creation time, using CREATE TABLE statement, or later with use of ALTER TABLE statement. 
Please see below a simplified syntax of these commands:

**CREATE TABLE:** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_name(
  .....
  [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
      [index_name] (index_col_name,...) reference_definition
  .....
)
```

**ALTER TABLE:** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html
ALTER ABLE tbl_name

```
ADD [CONSTRAINT [symbol]]
        FOREIGN KEY [index_name] (index_col_name,...)
        reference_definition
```

There are optional `CONSTRAINT [symbol]` clause in both of these syntaxes. This clause is used to give an explicit name to the constraint. In SQL the foreign key is **a constraint**.

The following syntax must be used in order to drop the foreign key:

**DROP FOREIGN KEY:** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_symbol
```

where `fk_symbol` is a **required name** of constraint used in CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE ADD commands.
If you didn't explicitely specify the name of constraint, MySql generate it's own internal name for the constraint.

You can check constraints' names querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` view.

For example:

```
create table aaa(
  x int primary key
  );

create table bbb(
  y int,
  constraint foreign key(y) references aaa(x)
);

select table_name, constraint_name, constraint_type
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE Table_name = 'bbb'
;
+ --------------- + -------------------- + -------------------- +
| table_name      | constraint_name      | constraint_type      |
+ --------------- + -------------------- + -------------------- +
| bbb             | bbb_ibfk_1           | FOREIGN KEY          |
+ --------------- + -------------------- + -------------------- +
1 rows
```

In the above example I didn't explicitely give a name to the foreign key constraint, and MySql assigned a name **bbb_ibfk_1** to this foreign key.
I can use this name to remove (drop) the foreign key from the table:

```
ALTER TABLE bbb
DROP FOREIGN KEY bbb_ibfk_1 ;
```